# Using Formula on Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series of climate data and some constant atmospheric values (Airpressure, etc) that I want to use in a formula to calculate latent Evapotranspiration. The formula is written as follows:

```
LET_a= (delta * (Rnet + G) + pa * cp * (VPD/Ra)) / (delta + pc * (1 + rs/Ra))
```

cp is a constant value (integer)
rs is a constant value (float)
The rest are all series with 300000 plus values.

A sample df. with similar values.

```
    df=pd.DataFrame([[0.078,-61.36,49.56,1.248,0.155,468.57],[0.077,-58.38,50.14,1.249,0.13,1968.02],[0.078,-54.44,50.36,1.249,0.12,3061.366]])

    df.columns=['delta', 'Rnet', 'G', 'pa', 'VPD', 'Ra',]

    cp=1005
    rs=79.36
    pc=0.0663
```

The expected results for these three rows should be the following: 
 -3.25, -3.77, -1.83

The following line is the same code as above only typed in by hand (using the first line of sample data and that produces the right result.

```
    LET_1 = (0.078 * (-61.36+49.56)+1.248*1005*(0.155/468.57)) /( 0.078 + 0.0663 * (1 + 79.37/468.57))
```

LET_1=-3.25

The problem is that something is happening with the numbers when I run this code (I don't get the right result) and I don't know why.

Is it because of the mix of series and floats? Does it need more () or a different way of writing?

In theory it should apply the formula to every single value in the series and produce a new series.

When I use the same formula just with numbers I get the right result. So it must be something in the "spelling" of the code.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your dataset.

Comment: Could you add this to your question and not to a comment? And furthermore please rewrite your code so that it can be executed with the data given in the DataFrame. Also posting an expected output would be great. Using your sample data my results are `[1811.175853, 1203.009187]`. Is that correct/expeced?

Comment: Thanks for editing your question and adding sample data! Could you also add an expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily calculate your data with the following line:

```
LET_a = (df.delta * (df.Rnet + df.G) + df.pa * cp * (df.VPD / df.Ra)) / (df.delta + pc * (1 + rs / df.Ra))
```

If you want to add the result as a column to your DataFrame, you can write it like this:

```
df['LET_a'] = (df.delta * (df.Rnet + df.G) + df.pa * cp * (df.VPD / df.Ra)) / (df.delta + pc * (1 + rs / df.Ra))
```

Both yield the same result:

```
# Out:    0    -3.250232
#         1    -3.778515
#         2    -1.842481
#      dtype: float64
```

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Variable naming conventions: Variables should be named in lowercase, underscores may be used. For dataframe columns you can also use other naming styles, but I still recommend sticking to the lowercase style, since this will make sure that you can always access the data with "dots" instead of having to write something like `df['A BC']` explicitly. Constants should be named in uppercase, if they are global or on modul-level. [Here is the python styleguide on variable naming.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)
2. Did you check the bracketing of your code? I cannot calculate the correct result of your code, even when typing the formula by hand. It looks like you misplaced some brackets. Bracketing rules in python are the same as for any other mathematical equation.

Comment: Actually the way I have it is that all the different variables are their own series. They are not together in 1 df. Does that matter?

Comment: Nope, that shouldn't matter. But the code will be easier to read AND faster to calculate if all of them are in the same DataFrame.

Comment: Brackets are as they should be according to the formula i'm using.

Comment: but the results dont match up.

Comment: Yes, but that is because your equation `LET_1 = (0.067873 * (-6.05+38.93)+1.25974*1005 etc...` is faulty. You are mixing up your values/variables. `0.067873` for example is **nowhere in your dataframe**. `RNet` for example is `-61.36`, `-58.38` or `-54.44` in the dataframe you posted. **But you evaluate your equation with `-6.05`**. This is nowhere near around 60. There is a factor of about 10. You really should check the sample values you posted.

Comment: this is a different sample using different numbers.

Comment: Looking at your edit, you **in fact changed the brackets of your formula**. Now it yields a completely different result. How do you expect me to give you a correct answer without the correct equation **AND even more with a completely different set of numbers to compare with?** Furthermore the results still don't match with those that you posted. You really should check your equation and the sample values.

Comment: sorry about that. ammended all brackets and data and results. check it now.

Comment: No worries! I edited my answer. It should match your sample data now.

Comment: Thank you so so much!! It worked!! I apologize for the terrible sample giving. Now I know how to do it properly!!

Comment: You are welcome! For the next question, following the links jezrael posted may help. These links include a few great explanations and examples on how to get the best answers. By the way: If my answer helped you, you may also accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df["LET_a"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.delta * (x.Rnet + x.G) + x.pa * cp * (x.VPD/x.Ra) / x.delta + pc * (1 + rs/x.Ra), axis=1)
df

    delta   Rnet      G      pa     VPD      Ra           LET_a
0   0.078   -61.36  49.56   1.248   0.155   468.570     5.174052
1   0.077   -58.38  50.14   1.249   0.130   1968.020    1.132096
2   0.078   -54.44  50.36   1.249   0.120   3061.366    0.992759
```

Comment: No! Don't use `apply` and `lambda` on a DataFrame! This completely kills the performance and is absolutely unpythonic!